# Не вызывается функция closeEvent() в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Довольно простая ситуация - мне нужно просто вызвать диалоговое окно при любой попытке закрыть приложение пользователем. В документации написано, что для этого необходимо переопределить функцию `closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);` И я так и сделал.

Файл .h:

`virtual void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) override;`

Файл .cpp:

```
void BaseMode::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "BaseMode::closeEvent ";
    // Вызов модального окна с вопросом, действительно ли пользователь хочет 
    // закрыть приложение
}
```

Однако при попытке закрыть приложение оно закрывается как обычно. Даже в консоль ничего не выводится, т.е. как будто эта функция и не переопределена вовсе, хотя она даже помечена как override и компилятор никаких ошибок или предупреждений не выдает.
Класс BaseMode наследуется от QWidget и является базовым, абстрактным(не знаю, имеет ли это значение) для двух других классов. Понимаю, что проблема где-то в моём классе, косвенно или явно дающая такое поведение, однако, в чем именно проблема, понять никак не могу. Класс BaseMode просто создает весь интерфейс одного лишь основного виджета, на котором уже все остальное (кнопки, лэйблы, меню, и пр.).

При создании нового проекта с одним только виджетом все работает отлично. И я никак не могу понять, что может быть такого в коде, чтобы в одном проекте функция `closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event)` работала нормально, а в другом нет.

Поскольку я не знаю, где именно может быть проблема, прикреплю сразу ссылку на весь код: https://github.com/PunchGott/Scanner

Comment: сложно дать ответ, надо больше кода (минимальный воспроизводимый пример). Если ваш BaseMode используется в цепочке наследования, то для базового класса он не будет вызван.

Comment: @goldstar_labs Кода конкретно чего? Сама то функция написана правильно, да и проблема скорее всего не в её переопределении, а где-то в моём проекте. Для простоты прикрепил ссылку на гитхаб с проектом. Класс BaseMode наследуется от QWidget, а сам является базовым для двух других классов. Я пробовал убирать чистые виртуальные функции в классе BaseMode и вызывать только объект этого класса (поскольку именно этот класс отвечает за интерфейс), но это никак не помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в коде есть класс `BaseMode` пронаследованный от `QWidget`. Данный класс уже является окном и способен отображать интерфейс.
В тоже время в самом классе BaseMode вы создаете еще один виджет

```
m_mainWidget = new QWidget;
```

который используется как главное окно интерфейса.

Соответственно у вас получается 2 виджета:

1) собственно сам объект класса BaseMode
2) созданный внутри класса BaseMode объект класса QWidget

Поскольку для объекта класса `BaseMode` не вызывается метод `show()`, то вы его даже не видите (хотя по факту он есть), соответственно для него не вызывается ивент `BaseMode::closeEvent()`. Данный ивент будет вызываться для объекта m_mainWidget.

**Вам необходимо избавиться от виджета m_mainWidget и работать непосредственно с вашим классом BaseMode.**

Теперь что происходит с классами-наследниками:

Создание виджета тут:

```
QPointer<ReceivingMode> receiving = new ReceivingMode();
```

Тут создается экземпляр класса ReceivingMode, который вызывает конструктор BaseMode, который опять же создает и отображает обычный QWidget

```
m_mainWidget = new QWidget
...
m_mainWidget->show();
```

Соответственно все ивенты опять идут мимо ReceivingMode

Правильно создавать и отображать именно тот виджет, который вам надо, вызывая для него show

т.е.

```
QPointer<ReceivingMode> receiving = new ReceivingMode();
receiving->show();
```

или же разместить вызов `show()` в конструкторе

P.S. надеюсь понятно, если что спрашивайте)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Даже стыдно как-то немного стало, что я за все это время, такие глупые и вроде бы очевидные ошибки допускал.